# Hugo definition of non-site level variables/parameters query

Tags: go, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I am using Hugo Universal Theme. I am new to static site generators. This question is for someone who is familiar with hugo templates.

In `layouts/partials/features.html` we can see where `$element.name` and `$element.name.description` are rendered:

```
{{ if isset .Site.Params "features" }}
{{ if .Site.Params.features.enable }}
{{ if gt (len .Site.Data.features) 0 }}
<section class="bar background-white">
    <div class="container">
        {{ range $index, $element := sort .Site.Data.features "weight" }}
        {{ if eq (mod $index 3) 0 }}
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
        {{ end }}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="box-simple">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="{{ .icon }}"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h3>{{ $element.name }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ $element.description | markdownify }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {{ if or (eq (mod $index 3) 2) (eq $index (sub (len $.Site.Data.features) 1 )) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
</section>
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

The data to be rendered in this case are defined in `data/features/consulting.yaml` as follows:

```
weight: 4
name: "Consulting"
icon: "fa fa-lightbulb-o"
description: "Fifth abundantly made Give sixth hath..."
```

What should I do to add new variable to the `yaml` file that can later then be rendered through the `html` file when hugo is compiling the site. I tried to simply add another parameter `param1` and then insert a corresponding line in the html file as `<p>{{ $element.param1 | markdownify }}</p>` just below description paragraph but got error

> ERROR 2018/08/23 10:42:42 Error while rendering "home" in "":
> template: index.html:22:11: executing "index.html" at <partial
> "features.ht...>: error calling partial: template:
> partials/features.html:18:56: executing "partials/features.html" at
> : wrong number of args for markdownify: want 1 got 0

Clearly it seems I have not been able to define the variable properly, but where should I do that? I can add another site variable to `config.toml`, but I want to learn how to make page specific variables that can be defined in `yaml/frontmatter` type entries. I tried reading about hugo variables but got bogged down in what is a variable and what is a shortcode. Many thanks for your help with this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a working answer, but I still do not fully understand how it fits with Hugo variable system, so a better answer and or comments are highly welcome.

It appears quite simple.  I had to define `url` variable in the `yaml` file:

```
name: "History"
position: "Hx"
url: "/blog/2018/08/23/01-history/"
```

and then use in the `html`  file like this:

```
{{ if .url }} 
    <a href="{{ .url }}"> 
    <h5>{{ .name }}</h5>
    </a>
{{ else }}
    <h5>{{ .name }}</h5>
{{ end }}
```

What it does is puts the .name in link tag, if .url is defined in .yaml. This works also if an absolute URL is given. So it appears that a page variable is referred to as `.myVariable`. the template authors used `$element.name` in another place as above, which confused me.

I also can refer to the parameter defined in the frontmatter as `.Params.name`

I found pointers at https://github.com/devcows/hugo-universal-theme/pull/166 and tested in adjusting the template; it works well.